# Which js Charts provide dynamic charting on Data

Tags: javascript, python, charts

i have used AM charts and Fusion charts to depict data graphically! For instance Bar chart on given data! what i need now is to provide user with option to change chart type dynamically as is on Talkwalker! one can change chart type on run time! anyone know of such charting tool? or suggestions how to acheieve such funtionality? [image: Figure of Talk walker is attached]

Answer (score 1):

Try C3.js library
[C3 JS](https://c3js.org/reference.html#data-type)

It has something called data.type which can take values like line,bar,area etc.

When you are re rendering the same data with different type, you can set data.type using chart.load api. [load api](https://c3js.org/reference.html#api-load) Here is how to use load api

Comment: well! that is over lay not re generation of graph as per requirement